# How can I put a description under image?

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have made a database with blob images and descriptions. The description is connected to the blob data with the same ID. In this code, the description is displayed right next to its image.

**Show Images Page**

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo`";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
echo '<'.'img src="id.php?id='.$data['id'].'">';
$short_description = substr($data['description'], 0, 10);
$long_description = $data['description'];
echo $long_description;


}

echo "<br><a href='Photosite.php'>Upload a Photo</a>";
```

**Converting blobs to jpegs for display page**

```
$id = abs($_GET['id']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo` WHERE id='$id'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die (mysql_error());
$image = $data['image'];
$description = $data['description'];


$jpgimage = imagecreatefromstring($image);




    $image_width = imagesx($jpgimage);
    $image_height = imagesy($jpgimage);

    $new_size = ($image_width + $image_height)/($image_width*($image_height/45));
    $new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
    $new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);


    imagecopyresized($new_image, $jpgimage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
      $imagearray = imagejpeg($new_image, null);
      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

       echo $imagearray;
```

My question is how can I *get the description to go UNDER the image displayed?* and not have image next to description next to image next to description and so forth...?

Big help thanks! And yes I know some of my functions are out-of-date, no need to remind me thanks!

Comment: I think the problem here is the positioning. You should try to include CSS on your codes.

Comment: Just post the html and css, this seems to have nothing to do with php and mysql.

Comment: You probably just need `echo '<br />'` before `echo $long_description;`

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you do this `echo '<'.'img`?

Comment: @BlackHatShadow I haven't learned CSS yet I was hoping I could try to do this without it. But I feel like the description and jpg are not really "attached". I want to have something where if this image is posted then this description will be posted with it. I am posting an image then text separately in this code, see what I mean?

Comment: @cryptic haha I am not sure, it is messy but it works. I will clean it up soon!

Comment: @jeroen see my comment to BlackHat

Comment: @Celeritas if I do that all the descriptions and photos get out of order and looks really bad. Which continues my saying how they are not "attached"

Comment: @NickD It's impossible to trouble shoot this further just knowing "everything's out of order". Can you take a screen shot and post it here? The point of CSS is to format the display of a webpage, and this is certainly a formatting issue.

Comment: @Nick D: Have you tried the 1st answer? I think you are making a thumbnail of photos with long descriptions. There are lot of solutions. You could use `HTML5` or `CSS3`. purely its up to you.

Comment: @BlackHatShadow Yes it worked thanks, I need to start learning HTML and CSS now!

Comment: @Celeritas Thanks it was formatting issues, I need to move a little away from PHP and start learning more HTML and CSS thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want images next to each other with descriptions below each image, then:

```
<?php
$max_width = '200px'; // Set this to whatever the image's width is.

$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo`";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
    // short_description doesn't look like it's being used... ??
    $short_description = substr($data['description'], 0, 10);
    $long_description = $data['description'];
    echo '<div style="float:left;width:'.$max_width.';">';
    echo '    <img src="id.php?id='.$data['id'].'" />';
    echo '    <br style="clear:both;" />';
    echo      $long_description;
    echo '</div>';
}
echo "<br style="clear:both;"><a href='Photosite.php'>Upload a Photo</a>";
```

Otherwise if you want images underneath each other with descriptions beneath image, then:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM `photo`.`photo`";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
    // short_description doesn't look like it's being used... ??
    $short_description = substr($data['description'], 0, 10);
    $long_description = $data['description'];
    echo '<div>';
    echo '    <img src="id.php?id='.$data['id'].'">';
    echo '    <br style="clear:both;" />';
    echo      $long_description;
    echo '</div>';
}
echo "<br style="clear:both;"><a href='Photosite.php'>Upload a Photo</a>";
```

Comment: Not sure what you changed in your edit but the first one, which is what I needed, worked thanks! Just ignore short description that will be used later. I think I need to start learning more HTML!

Comment: glad i could help! the edits were more visual aspects than anything, and a bug fix in the second example. an up-vote with your acceptance is always appreciated as well :D

Answer (score 0):

Try a line break before the description. You could also consider a simple two row one column table.